# Using variable range

Tags: excel, vba

I have this range

```vb
Range("G8:G" & Range("F" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(-1, 0).Row)
```

, and I would like to replace the values with variables because the range will change. I was thinking of using `Cells` like `Range(Cells(8, trow)` etc, but I can't get it to work. Does anyone know how I would replace the range items with variables? I want to do this because the column will change depending on how much data I have, but it will always start at 8.

Comment: Instead of `Range(Cells(8, trow)`, remove the `range` so it's `cells(8, trow)`. Edit: `cells` goes by row, column so `cells(8, trow)` is row 8 and whatever column the variable trow holds.

Comment: so something like 

Cells(8, trow) & Cells(trow) & cells(rows.count, trow).End(xlup).offset(-1,0).Row ?

I am trying to wrap my head around going from like G8 to 8 through cells

Comment: I would find whatever `Range("F" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(-1, 0).Row)` is first, store that to a variable then you can do `range(cells(8,"G"),cells(variable,"G")`. I feel you may have row/column confused?

Comment: `ws.Range(ws.Cells(8, colNum), ws.Cells(ws.rows.count, colNum).end(xlUp).offset(-1))` where `colNum` is the number of the column you want (or letter, but numbers are typically easier to code with) and `ws` is the worksheet you're interested in.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something along these lines:

```vb
Dim ws As Worksheet, rng as range, col

Set ws = ActiveSheet 'or whatever

col = 3 'or "C", for example

Set rng = ws.Range(ws.Cells(8, col), _
                   ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, col).End(xlUp).Offset(-1))
```